# Does methods such as Generalized Mersenne are safe way to find p and q?

Tags: rsa, key-generation

There are many [methods](http://primes.utm.edu/top20/index.php) for finding very large primes fast. Most of them have complete lists.

Is it possible an attacker try to guess that p or q was generated using a such kind of method?

If yes, shall I try to check my prime match a case like this one, when I generate primes by pure random numbers *(generate a random number and check)*? Even if the probability is too low *(in the case I want to very sure of the quality of the key)*?

Comment: Is this question a better fit on crypto?

Comment: @EricG : I think it fit also here too, but I don't need to create an account on crypto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody generates primes for RSA keys using these methods specialized for very large primes, for two reasons:

1. Such primes have a lot of mathematical structure (there are just not any prime, but very specific cases) which can only weaken the algorithm if used for an RSA key pair.
2. For RSA we don't want large primes, only "medium-sized" primes. Indeed, if you have a 2048-bit RSA key, then you *know* that the prime factors cannot be longer than 2048 bits (that's a mathematical certainty), so in particular they cannot have been generated with a method which produces primes with millions of bits.

It is useless to check whether a randomly generated prime falls into a "special category": the probability of such an occurrence is much lower (really much lower, by a factor of many gazillions) than the probability that right now, as you read these lines, a crow afflicted with schizophrenia crashes through your window and maims you by plucking out your left eye. If you don't worry about ophthalmologist crows, then don't worry about primes for RSA keys.

Comment: Except large keys slow down encryption *(hundreds of ko long)*, are there any other drawbacks with using large primes.

Comment: There is "slow down", and there is "slow _really_ down". When it takes hours or days to perform a single RSA computation, I don't call that "slow"; I call that "does not work".

Comment: And except this, are there many other things? I've heard it tend to make times attacks easier.